# Filter specific to a panel in grafana

Tags: variables, parameters, grafana

My requirement is to create two or more panels in a dashboard and the column names in the select statement must be chosen from variables displayed.But since variables are common across the dashboards, the variable chosen in one panel, the same is getting reflected in other panel as well.

this is the query i'm using-->SELECT
"time" AS "time",$parameter FROM sample
WHERE $__timeFilter("time") and deviceid='$deviceid' ORDER BY 1

here $parameter is the variable i'm passing and this need to be specific to a panel.
for eg: I can choose temperature for one panel and humidity to another panel

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Maybe there is an add-on for that